# mainwindow.obj: -1: error: LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol __imp__RegOpenKeyExW

Tags: c++, qt, linker-errors

I want to get Serial port list through windows function `RegOpenKeyExW` inside Qt, but encounter the following linking error:

> mainwindow.obj: -1: error: LNK2019: Unresolved external symbol
>   __imp__RegOpenKeyExW @ 20 in the function "public: class QString __thiscall MainWindow :: getcomm (int, class QString)"

Comment: Have you linked the libraries whichever they might be.

Comment: Make sure you've linked against `advapi32`.

Comment: When I add this code  "#pragma comment(lib,"advapi32.lib") " to my project,Thus it don`t have error occur,Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Per [Shijang.Guo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7665753/shijiang-guo)'s comment on the question:

`#pragma comment(lib,"advapi32.lib")`